# Possible card hands

Tags: probability, combinatorics, card-games

Suppose you have a deck of $20$ cards with $4$ suits and ranks {A, K, Q, J, 10}. Let's say you draw 4 cards at random (without replacement). What is the probability you will have exactly 3 suits?

> I tried $\frac{20\cdot4\cdot15\cdot10}{20\cdot19\cdot18\cdot17}$ but this is not correct I think. What am I doing wrong and what would instead get me the correct answer?

Comment: Say the first three cards you choose are of a different suit. Then you have $20\cdot15\cdot 10$ options for the first three cards. The fourth card is of a suit with 4 cards in the deck, so you have 12 options. Your answer is then $\frac{20\cdot 15 \cdot 10\cdot 12}{20\cdot 19\cdot 18 \cdot 17}= \frac{100}{323}$.

Comment: @JuliusJ.what if you choose the same suited card 2nd? Does this account for that case?

Comment: thank you for your question. Out of the $4\choose 2$ ways the same suited cards could show up, I only counted that half of the cases with one of them in last place. The final answer should hence be twice my original claim at $\frac{200}{323}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is easier if we consider it without order.

Number of possible 4-card hands : ${20 \choose 4}=4845$

Number of hands with exactly three suits : ${4\choose 1}{5\choose 2}{3 \choose 2}{5\choose 1}{5\choose 1}=3000$

Probability $\frac{3000}{4845}=\frac{200}{323}$